# No child records in Shared Database for parent record using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: swift, cloudkit, nsmanagedobject, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I've set up a Core Data mirroring to CloudKit using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. My simplified data structure consists of List and Item. List have one-to-many relationship ***items*** with many Items, Item has ***parentList*** property.

When I am getting CKRecord associated with List NSManagedObject and sharing it, I expect all child Items to be shared too. I know, I can set parentRecord property for each CKRecord associated with the List

```
childRecord.setParent(parentRecord)
```

But I believe there is some smart way to avoid doing that manually, because everything is mirroring automatically and it looks stupid to start handling each single property manually to only set parentRecord.

Is there any way to do that for NSManagedObjects? Because my custom relationship does not mean for CloudKit that the List is parent for the Item.